# SparkStreaming consumer Kafka

Tags: streaming, scala

Estou fazendo um teste com sparkstreaming consumindo de um tópico do kafka. Quando start o job ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

```
18/06/06 20:39:25 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Error connecting to localhost:9999 - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver.onStart(SocketInputDStream.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply$mcV$sp(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:189)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Se eu abrir o prompt e acessar via nc -lp 9999, funciona. Más preciso consumir o tópico. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Estou usando Spark 2.3.0 e o Kafka 0-10_2

Segue meu código:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig

import scala.collection.mutable

object WorldCount_Kafka {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .setAppName("WorldCount-kafka")

    //Read messages in batch of 20 seconds
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(20))
    val sc = ssc.sparkContext

    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val kafkaParam = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
    kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092")
    kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test")
    kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true")
    kafkaParam.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000")

    //Configure Spark to listen messages in topic test
    val topicList = List("first_topic")

    // Read value of each message from Kafka and return it
    val messageStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
      LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String,String](topicList, kafkaParam)
    )

    val lines = messageStream.map(consumerRecord => consumerRecord.value().asInstanceOf[String])

    // Break every message into words and return list of words
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))

    // Take every word and return Tuple with (word,1)
    val wordMap = words.map(word => (word, 1))

    // Count occurance of each word
    val wordCount = wordMap.reduceByKey((first, second) => first + second)

    //Print the word count
    wordCount.print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: Essa porta 9999 é do processo de streaming que você está fazendo? Ele está jogando erro porque não está fechando conexão com essa porta. O default bootstrap server é a 127.0.0.1:9092 mesmo, você já tentou fazer um teste substituindo o localhost pelo 127.0.0.1? O ambiente é um docker?